# Using a mocking framework with .net V2

Tags: .net, unit-testing, .net-2.0, mocking

We are still on .net v2 (C#) due to issues with getting customers to upgrade.  I am looking at using a mocking framework, but **don’t wish to have method names as strings** all over the place.

In the past I have used Moq, but don’t believe it will work with .net v2.

What options should I be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rhino Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) works fine.

Comment: Does it let me setup mocks in a "save" way (using .net 2), e.g. without having to pass the method names as strings?

Comment: Yes. In the 'record' phase of your test, you make calls to the interface methods you want it to mock, passing in expected parameter values. Internally, Rhino Mocks records these dummy interface calls for use in the 'playback' phase. IMO it's more clever than Moq because it was designed before `Expression` existed.